Offset Explorer: Unable to open the keystore using the given password
I have generated a truststore and a keystore using which I need to connect to my AWS MSK cluster through Offset Explorer 2.0. I am facing an issue while adding a new connection in the Offset Explorer and while trying to test the new connection. I have specified the Zookeeper and bootstrap details of the MSK cluster, however I am getting an Error message: Unable to open the Keystore using the given password. I have manually tested the keystore password on my Windows local machine, it works there but not on the Offset Explorer. I don't know what the issue is. Can someone please help me establish connection with the MSK cluster.
I have created a signed cert with the AWS Private CA and imported it to the Keystore. I dont know why i am getting this issue.
